# Solution Verification( a homoeomorphism $h: \mathbb{R} \to (-1,1)$)

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that there exists a homeomorphism $h: \mathbb{R} \to (-1,1)$.

Attempt: I think $f(x) = \tan^{-1}(2/\pi) x$ is such a homeomorphism because the function is 1-1 , onto ,continuous and it's inverse image is also continuous.

Am I right?

Comment: You have to prove your claim.

Comment: Another one: Consider $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ for $x\in \Bbb R$. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism from $\Bbb R$ onto $(-1,1)$ with inverse $f^{-1}(y):=\frac{y}{1-|y|}$ for $y\in (-1,1)$.

Comment: This is correct.